# Поиск файла по расширению C++

Tags: c++, linux, файлы, поиск, g++

Нужно найти файл по расширению в известной директории. Для винды существует такое решение:

```
FindFirstFile("Some/Directory/Some/*.some");
```

А как такое же провернуть под Linux, ибо подход описанный выше не работает и не заработает в Linux. Уже имеется вот такой код:

```
cout << "Type path - ";
string path_to;
getline(cin, path_to);
cout << "Type filename - ";
string filename;
getline(cin, filename);
string result = path_to + "/" + filename;
FindFirstFile(result);//знаю, что другое что-то использовать нужно вот и спрашиваю.
```

Вчера начал изучать C++ после C#, объясните простым языком

Comment: Говорите, что нужен поиск по расширению (с неизвестным именем, получается), но я в `"Some/Directory/Some/File.some"` нет символов `*` и `?`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо за замечание. Код исправил, но это ничего не меняет. вопрос заключается в другом.

Comment: Сейчас напишу ответ. Вам поиск в подпапках тоже нужен, или нет?

Comment: FindFirstFile это WinAPI. Это как бы вызов к системе Windows если хочется в линукс то следует поискать линукс вариант. Ещё можно поискать кроссплатформенную библиотеку.

Comment: man 3 glob - надеюсь, то что нужно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В С++17 появился новый крутой инклюд для работы с файловой системой: [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

Им и воспользуйтесь.

<sup>Код ниже делает поиск непосредственно в выбранной папке, без подпапок. Если нужен рекурсивный поиск, замените `directory_iterator` на `recursive_directory_iterator`.</sup>

```
#include <exception>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace fs = std::filesystem; // Чтобы не писать `std::filesystem` каждый раз

int main()
{
    std::string directory_name = "some/directory";
    std::string extension = ".ext";

    try // Может быть исключение, например, если папки не существует
    {
        for (auto &p : fs::directory_iterator(directory_name)) // Для всех файлов в папке
        {
            if (!fs::is_regular_file(p.status()))
                continue; // Пропускаем, если это не простой файл, а папка или что-то другое

            std::string name(p.path().filename());

            // Проверяем, что имя заканчивается нужным расширением
            // В С++20 можно будет просто `bool match = name.ends_with(extension);`
            bool match = !name.compare(name.size() - extension.size(), extension.size(), extension);
            if (!match)
                continue;

            // Тут делаем с путем то, что нужно
            std::cout << name << '\n';
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

Чтобы это работало в GCC, нужен флаг `-std=c++17` (или `-std=gnu++17`), и нужно подключить библиотеку `-lstdc++fs`.

Comment: Впросы: Как добавить флаг в GCC(по иронии именно его и использую в Linux), Зачем писать постоянно std::...

Comment: на этапе #include <filesystem> уже не работает. помечает как ошибку

Comment: @МаксимДонец Как добавить флаг зависит от того, как именно вы используете ГЦЦ. Запускаете из командой строки? Или из IDE (если да, из какой)?

Comment: @МаксимДонец Предлагаете писать `using namespace std;`? Есть мнение (с которым я согласен), что [это плохая практика](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Кроме того, в некоторых случаях он может приводить к [весьма таинственным ошибкам](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc1a022f9fcad93b). Да и вообще, имхо с `std::` код нагляднее.

Comment: Нет я совсем не пишу такого. Не знаю для чего это делается. 
Использую NetBeans

Comment: @МаксимДонец Так без `using` убрать `std::` не получится - не скомпилируется. *"Использую NetBeans"* У меня она не стоит, так что нужно гуглить. Можно на всякий случай обновить ГЦЦ, `<filesystem>` только недавно добавили.